# Zagreb - Belgrade train schedules

Tags: trains, croatia, serbia, zagreb, belgrade

I know there are also buses between these cities, but I'm trying to find timetables for trains.

[According to Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Belgrade.htm#Zagreb_),

> A daytime train leaves *Belgrade* every day at 11:03 arriving Zagreb
>   18:11 & Ljubljana 20:56.  It's a leisurely trip across the former
>   Yugoslavia on a route once used by the Simplon Orient Express.  Bring
>   your own provisions and perhaps some beer or wine...

**But what about the other direction, Zagreb to Belgrade?** With quick look, I could not find that info on Seat 61, and the [Croatian train company](http://www.hzpp.hr/en) site doesn't show anything for Belgrade. Info from some official resource as well as recent first-hand experiences are both welcome.

Comment: Most (famous) trains run both directions and the Seat 61 site does not always mention the 'return to base' one.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the schedules via the [website of the Serbian Railways](http://w3.srbrail.rs/zsredvoznje/en). Note that you have to use the Serbian spelling of Belgrade, i.e. BEOGRAD:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I entered your found train into the [German travel site](http://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/index.shtml), and found that same train. Then I clicked the ⇅ arrows, (the ones that reverse the direction of search) and the results were alike. One day train and one overnight.
11:05 to 17:32 and 23:48 to 5:52.

I would suggest you to run the site for a day you want to travel, I checked it for a couple of days from now.

Internet search only but I do find the German rail site rather reliable. (I would try to book through one of the involved national rail sites if possible, not the German one.)

Comment: If you are talking about **Bahn.de**, mention it by name, because everyone knows it by that name. It certainly was an improvement, but keep your bloody answer.

Comment: Anyway, what I was really going to say: Thanks! Back in Zagreb, a hostel employee dug up and printed me the [info from Bahn.de](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnr0C.jpg) as well. Apparently hzpp.hr (in Croatian) somewhere said “international timetables” and that was just a link to Bahn.de!